Proof that the intersection of an arbitrary family of algebraic sets is an algebraic set.
If I want to prove that "the intersection of an arbitrary family of algebraic sets is an algebraic set", so it comes down to proving that $$\bigcap_{i \in I} Z(I_{i})=Z\left( \bigcup_i I_i \right)$$
from where $\{I_i \}$ is an arbitrary family of ideals of $K[X]$ with $K$ is a field, and $Z(I_i)$ is a colection of algebraic sets in the affine space. Let's try
"$\subseteq$" Let $(a_1, \dots, a_n) \in \bigcap_i Z(I_i)$, then $(a_1, \dots, a_n) \in Z(I_i)$ for all $i \in I$, wich means that for all $f \in I_i$, $f(a_1, \dots, a_n)=0$ ($i \in \{1, \dots, n \}$), in particular there exists $I_i$ s.t. $f \in I_i$ for some $i \in I$ with $f(a_1, \dots, a_n)=0$, so $(a_1, \dots, a_n) \in Z\left( \bigcup_i I_i \right)$. Well, this could be one way I consider; but I don't see clear the other implication, any suggestions? I would be grateful.

Let $(a_1, \cdots, a_n) \in Z\left( \bigcup_i I_i \right)$. It means that $f((a_1, \cdots, a_n))=0$ for all $f \in I_i$. Therefore $(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n) \in \bigcap_{i \in I} Z(I_{i})$. This proves $\supseteq$.
